# Date function to bypass weekends and specific dates

Tags: php

I am trying to implement the code below to force dates to skip weekends and holiday array. The weekend part is working but I am having difficulty with the holiday section, here is my code:

```
$holidayDates = array(
    '10-10-2017', '11-10-2017'
);

$fcount = 0;
$temp = strtotime("9-10-2017"); 

while ($fcount < 1) {
    $nextfcount = strtotime('+1 weekday', $temp);
    $nextfcount2 = date('d-m-Y', $temp);

    if (!in_array($nextfcount2, $holidayDates)) {
        $fcount++;
    }

    $temp = $nextfcount;
} 

$newDater = date("d-m-Y", $temp);
```

Comment: just don't... Please Name your variables. it's not `$temp`, it's `$start`.

Comment: In as much as i appreciate your comment, i really do not understand what you asked me to do...thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let me debug this for you:

```
$holidayDates = array(
    '10-10-2017', '11-10-2017'
);

$fcount = 0;

// 1. $temp is a terrible name for a variable
$temp = strtotime("9-10-2017"); 

// 2. in other words - if $fcount == 1, exit loop
while ($fcount < 1) {

    // 3. $temp is now the 9th
    $nextfcount = strtotime('+1 weekday', $temp);

    // 4. $nextfcount2 is now the 10th
    $nextfcount2 = date('d-m-Y', $temp);

    if (!in_array($nextfcount2, $holidayDates)) {
        // 5. Yes, found your date. $fcount is now 1
        $fcount++;
    }

    // 6. $temp is now the 10th
    $temp = $nextfcount;

    // 7. $fcount is now 1, `while` condition is met, exit loop
} 

// 8. The date is now the 10th
$newDater = date("d-m-Y", $temp);
```

You question is much too vague for me to provide you with a quality answer.

I will assume, you want to get `12-10-2017` as the result of your loop. This code will do the trick:

```
<?php

$holidayDates = [
    '10-10-2017', 
    '11-10-2017',
];

$foundCounter = 0;

$theDate = strtotime("9-10-2017"); 

while ($foundCounter < 1) {

    $theDate = strtotime('+1 weekday', $theDate);

    if (!in_array(date('d-m-Y', $theDate), $holidayDates)) {
        $foundCounter++;
    }

} 

$newDater = date("d-m-Y", $theDate);
var_dump($newDater);
// string(10) "12-10-2017"
```

https://3v4l.org/DcWBZ